# How to rescale a STL surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, stl, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I've imported a STL file in Matlab with the function stlread.

My question is, how can we rescale it with an arbitrary size factor (for instance, suppose you want to halve its dimensions)?

Here there is my piece of code in which the stl is imported and viewed:

```
fv = stlread ( 'Femur_Head.stl' );


patch(fv,'FaceColor',       [0.8 0.8 1.0], ...
         'EdgeColor',       'none',        ...
         'FaceLighting',    'gouraud',     ...
         'AmbientStrength', 0.15);

% Add a camera light, and tone down the specular highlighting
camlight('headlight');
material('dull');

axis([-50 50 -50 50 0 80]);
 
view([-135 35]);
 
title('Femur Head');
 
xlabel('X');ylabel('Y');zlabel('Z');
 
% Fix the axes scaling, and set a nice view angle
 
axis('image');
view([-135 35]);
 
hold on
```

View:

[image]

Comment: Just play with `fv.Points`, e.g. `fv.Points=fv.Points*2`

Comment: @Ander Biguri  Thank you for your answer. When I use your suggestion, I get: "Referenc to non-existent field 'Points'"

Comment: Depends on the MATLAB version. What does `fv` contain? It should contain a list of points with some name, and a list of triangles pointing at which points they use. You can modify the list of points as you want, triangles will still be made of them